# is there any automated way to extract the "pip install"ed dependecies from PyCharm project?

Tags: python, pycharm

I installed a bunch of dependencies in PyCharm terminal using pip install.

The project works.

Now I want to take all those dependencies and put in requirements.txt file. However, I do not remember what I installed. It's been a while. I can manually recreate the list of installed packages by trial and error. However, is there any automated way to extract the "`pip install`"ed dependecies from PyCharm project?

Comment: Do you want a minimal set of your direct dependencies (i.e. what you `pip install X`'d), or are you ok with a verbose list of all the installed dependencies and their sub-dependencies? The latter is just `pip freeze`

Comment: Do note that dependency management is a lot simpler if you use a modern build system / frontend (see [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/)). `requirements.txt` is outdated. For example, if you use poetry, you'd already have a minimal description of your dependencies in `pyproject.toml` and could get an informative dependency graph with `poetry show --tree`

Comment: The pip documentation explains exactly how to get installed modules

Comment: @Brian61354270 yes I'm looking for the minimal set, only what I installed as pip install

Comment: @john In that case, there's no way to do that with pip. pip doesn't track any information about previous installs. You'll need to use a dependency locking building frontend, like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) (3rd party) or [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) (same makers as pip).

Comment: @Brian61354270 I see then this is the answer. It is not feasible in the current setting. Please post as an answer so that other people who may have a similar questions may benefit from it.

Comment: @john, can you clarify why my answer won't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) creates a `requirements.txt` with only **used** libraries in the specified project.

From the docs;

> Why not pip freeze?
>
> - pip freeze only saves the packages that are installed with pip    install in your environment.
> - pip freeze saves all packages in the environment including those that you don’t use in your current project (if you don’t have
>   virtualenv).
> - and sometimes you just need to create requirements.txt for a new project without installing modules.

Answer (score 0):

pycharm create a venv for each project , so if you run :

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

you will have all your dependencies and their versions in requirements.txt .
I hope that helped.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is looking to only get the direct dependencies of their project, not all packages currently installed.

Comment: if he have venv (almost all pycharm project do) he will have only the dependencies of his project .

Comment: The issue is the difference between direct and indirect dependencies. Say package `X` has 100 dependencies, and the OP ran `pip install X`. They want to get back `X`, not the 101 lines that are in `pip freeze`. And fwiw, that's hardly unrealistic. The tree of Jupyters dependencies has 427 package entries (with duplicates from shared-dependencies).